# Force Network Activated Plugin to Run After Site Level Plugins

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite

I have a custom plugin I created and network activated it on WordPress Multi-Site install. I plan to use this plugin to override/enhance functionality for plugins available on my installation.

The problem is, it looks like plugins at the network activation level run first, then the plugins that were activated on a site-by-site basis run their actions. I need my network activated plugin to run last so I can override actions and filters effectively.

Looking at the plugin load order in the database for my main site doesn't even show my plugin so how can I make just my one custom plugin run last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which any plugins are loaded is not guaranteed and should not be relied upon.

Instead, if you have processes which should happen after the plugins are loaded, then you should put those inside a function and then connect that function to the `plugins_loaded` action hook.